# Minify Angular app on deploy

Tags: angularjs, heroku, gruntjs

What is the best way to minify an Angular app before deploying it to Heroku? Can I add a Gruntfile? Will it be run automatically on Heroku when I push? Do I need to add something like grunt.registerTask('heroku:production', 'build'); and then in that task add code which uses an uglify plugin?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I can add postinstall in my package.json and Heroku will run uglify.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/node-with-grunt